# Is it possible to change CAD model dimensions using Forge APIs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am very new to Autodesk Forge and am still learning my way through NodeJS (since thats the language I prefer learning Forge in). Any help would be appreciated. I have gone through the [Learn Forge Tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/). However, I was wondering,

1. Do any of the current Forge APIs allow to change the dimension of a CAD model uploaded on OSS. For example, can we achieve the goal of changing, lets say, one of the specified dimensions of a model while seeing its updated shape in the viewer?
2. Are there any current implementations wherein I can use the APIs to communicate, lets say, with CAD models stored on a cloud database like MongoDB. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying Forge, hope it can help with your solution:), and here is my answer to your 2 questions:

1. If you want to update the model that is uploaded into Autodesk OSS, yes, currently, Forge provided the Design Automation API that you can use to create/update/export for your design files, it supports AutoCAD already, and Inventor/Revit will be coming to the family very soon. The workflow should be:
   **Viewing the model in Forge Viewer** **-> Calling Design Automation API to change the model** **-> Create a new version of existing CAD file** **-> Calling Model Derivative API to translate it again** **-> Viewing the updated model in Forge viewer**.
2. If you are talking about viewing the CAD model from some other cloud storage, unfortunately, currently, we only support to translating/viewing the CAD model from some Autodesk SAAS Apps including BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team (formerly known as A360 Team), BIM 360 Docs, A360 Personal, and of course, the Autodesk Object Storage Service as you are using now.

Hope it answers your question, and good luck with Forge development.